# WOOCOMMERCE and cannot figure out how to have the header image across all pages

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I located this in Inspector but its not working, still defaults to a dummy background color of blue when I put this in CSS:

```
<div class="page-title-inner container align-center text-center flex-row-col medium-flex-wrap">
<div class="title-content flex-col">
<div class="title-breadcrumbs pb-half pt-half"></div>      </div>
</div>
#page-header-1359185174 .page-title-inner {
  min-height: 150px;
}
#page-header-1359185174 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#page-header-1359185174 .title-bg {
  background-image: url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/AZ-Flag.png);
}
#page-header-1359185174 .title-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
#page-header-1359185174 .featured-title {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

EDIT:
Dummy is the placeholder image. If you search the html for this it will show you where its appearing. This is the source from the home page. Im trying to do this via css and nor the UXbuilder as it does not show properly on the product or check out pages. https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/dummy-1.jpg

EDIT:
Here is the partial code, full code at link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8vaflqy9k25r40/HTML%20CODE.txt?dl=0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie9 loading-site no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html lang="en-US" class="ie8 loading-site no-js"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en-US" class="loading-site no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xmlrpc.php" />

                    <script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className + ' yes-js js_active js'</script>
                <script>(function(html){html.className = html.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js')})(document.documentElement);</script>
<title>Premier XXXXXXXXXXXXX</title>
<meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /><link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//fonts.googleapis.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title=" &raquo; Feed" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title=" &raquo; Comments Feed" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/comments/feed/" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"https:\/\/www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.8.2"}};
            !function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode;p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0);e=i.toDataURL();return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(!p||!p.fillText)return!1;switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])?!1:!s([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!s([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]);case"emoji":return!s([10084,65039,8205,55357,56613],[10084,65039,8203,55357,56613])}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(n=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(n.concatemoji):n.wpemoji&&n.twemoji&&(c(n.twemoji),c(n.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='seedprod-global-admin-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/coming-soon/public/css/global-admin.css?ver=6.6.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='dashicons-inline-css' type='text/css'>
[data-font="Dashicons"]:before {font-family: 'Dashicons' !important;content: attr(data-icon) !important;speak: none !important;font-weight: normal !important;font-variant: normal !important;text-transform: none !important;line-height: 1 !important;font-style: normal !important;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale !important;}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='admin-bar-inline-css' type='text/css'>

            @font-face {
                font-family: 'w3tc';
            src: url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/fonts/w3tc.eot');
            src: url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/fonts/w3tc.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                 url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/fonts/w3tc.woff') format('woff'),
                 url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/fonts/w3tc.ttf') format('truetype'),
                 url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/fonts/w3tc.svg#w3tc') format('svg');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
        .w3tc-icon:before{
            content:'\0041'; top: 2px;
            font-family: 'w3tc';
        }
</style>
<style id='wp-block-library-inline-css' type='text/css'>
:root{--wp-admin-theme-color:#007cba;--wp-admin-theme-color-darker-10:#006ba1;--wp-admin-theme-color-darker-20:#005a87;--wp-admin-border-width-focus:2px}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),(min-resolution:192dpi){:root{--wp-admin-border-width-focus:1.5px}}:root .has-pale-pink-background-color{background-color:#f78da7}:root .has-vivid-red-background-color{background-color:#cf2e2e}:root .has-luminous-vivid-orange-background-color{background-color:#ff6900}:root .has-luminous-vivid-amber-background-color{background-color:#fcb900}:root .has-light-green-cyan-background-color{background-color:#7bdcb5}:root .has-vivid-green-cyan-background-color{background-color:#00d084}:root .has-pale-cyan-blue-background-color{background-color:#8ed1fc}:root .has-vivid-cyan-blue-background-color{background-color:#0693e3}:root .has-vivid-purple-background-color{background-color:#9b51e0}:root .has-white-background-color{background-color:#fff}:root .has-very-light-gray-background-color{background-color:#eee}:root .has-cyan-bluish-gray-background-color{background-color:#abb8c3}:root .has-very-dark-gray-background-color{background-color:#313131}:root .has-black-background-color{background-color:#000}:root .has-pale-pink-color{color:#f78da7}:root .has-vivid-red-color{color:#cf2e2e}:root .has-luminous-vivid-orange-color{color:#ff6900}:root .has-luminous-vivid-amber-color{color:#fcb900}:root .has-light-green-cyan-color{color:#7bdcb5}:root .has-vivid-green-cyan-color{color:#00d084}:root .has-pale-cyan-blue-color{color:#8ed1fc}:root .has-vivid-cyan-blue-color{color:#0693e3}:root .has-vivid-purple-color{color:#9b51e0}:root .has-white-color{color:#fff}:root .has-very-light-gray-color{color:#eee}:root .has-cyan-bluish-gray-color{color:#abb8c3}:root .has-very-dark-gray-color{color:#313131}:root .has-black-color{color:#000}:root .has-vivid-cyan-blue-to-vivid-purple-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#0693e3,#9b51e0)}:root .has-vivid-green-cyan-to-vivid-cyan-blue-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#00d084,#0693e3)}:root .has-light-green-cyan-to-vivid-green-cyan-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#7adcb4,#00d082)}:root .has-luminous-vivid-amber-to-luminous-vivid-orange-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#fcb900,#ff6900)}:root .has-luminous-vivid-orange-to-vivid-red-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#ff6900,#cf2e2e)}:root .has-very-light-gray-to-cyan-bluish-gray-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#eee,#a9b8c3)}:root .has-cool-to-warm-spectrum-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#4aeadc,#9778d1 20%,#cf2aba 40%,#ee2c82 60%,#fb6962 80%,#fef84c)}:root .has-blush-light-purple-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#ffceec,#9896f0)}:root .has-blush-bordeaux-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#fecda5,#fe2d2d 50%,#6b003e)}:root .has-purple-crush-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#34e2e4,#4721fb 50%,#ab1dfe)}:root .has-luminous-dusk-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#ffcb70,#c751c0 50%,#4158d0)}:root .has-hazy-dawn-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#faaca8,#dad0ec)}:root .has-pale-ocean-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#fff5cb,#b6e3d4 50%,#33a7b5)}:root .has-electric-grass-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#caf880,#71ce7e)}:root .has-subdued-olive-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#fafae1,#67a671)}:root .has-atomic-cream-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#fdd79a,#004a59)}:root .has-nightshade-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#330968,#31cdcf)}:root .has-midnight-gradient-background{background:linear-gradient(135deg,#020381,#2874fc)}.has-small-font-size{font-size:.8125em}.has-normal-font-size,.has-regular-font-size{font-size:1em}.has-medium-font-size{font-size:1.25em}.has-large-font-size{font-size:2.25em}.has-huge-font-size,.has-larger-font-size{font-size:2.625em}.has-text-align-center{text-align:center}.has-text-align-left{text-align:left}.has-text-align-right{text-align:right}#end-resizable-editor-section{display:none}.aligncenter{clear:both}.items-justified-left{justify-content:flex-start}.items-justified-center{justify-content:center}.items-justified-right{justify-content:flex-end}.items-justified-space-between{justify-content:space-between}.screen-reader-text{border:0;clip:rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);-webkit-clip-path:inset(50%);clip-path:inset(50%);height:1px;margin:-1px;overflow:hidden;padding:0;position:absolute;width:1px;word-wrap:normal!important}.screen-reader-text:focus{background-color:#ddd;clip:auto!important;-webkit-clip-path:none;clip-path:none;color:#444;display:block;font-size:1em;height:auto;left:5px;line-height:normal;padding:15px 23px 14px;text-decoration:none;top:5px;width:auto;z-index:100000}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='woocommerce-inline-inline-css' type='text/css'>
.woocommerce form .form-row .required { visibility: visible; }
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-optimize-global-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-optimize/css/wp-optimize-global-3-1-12.min.css?ver=3.1.12' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flatsome-woocommerce-wishlist-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/inc/integrations/wc-yith-wishlist/wishlist.css?ver=3.10.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flatsome-main-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/flatsome.css?ver=3.14.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<style id='flatsome-main-inline-css' type='text/css'>
@font-face {
                font-family: "fl-icons";
                font-display: block;
                src: url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.eot?v=3.14.3);
                src:
                    url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.eot#iefix?v=3.14.3) format("embedded-opentype"),
                    url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.woff2?v=3.14.3) format("woff2"),
                    url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.ttf?v=3.14.3) format("truetype"),
                    url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.woff?v=3.14.3) format("woff"),
                    url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.svg?v=3.14.3#fl-icons) format("svg");
            }
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flatsome-shop-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/flatsome-shop.css?ver=3.14.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flatsome-style-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome-child/style.css?ver=3.0' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='flatsome-googlefonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato%3Aregular%2C700%2C400%2C700%7CDancing+Script%3Aregular%2C400&#038;display=swap&#038;ver=3.9' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='csshero-main-stylesheet-css'  href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/csshero-static-style-flatsome-child.css?ver=322' type='text/css' media='all' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function w3tc_popupadmin_bar(url) {
                return window.open(url, '', 'width=800,height=600,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes');
            }
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0' id='jquery-core-js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.3.2' id='jquery-migrate-js'></script>
<link rel="https://api.w.org/" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/json" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/55" /><link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 5.8.2" />
<meta name="generator" content="WooCommerce 5.9.0" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com%2F&#038;format=xml" />
    <style>
        #wp-admin-bar-wpcss-css-hero-go a,#wp-admin-bar-wpcss-css-hero-go:hover a  {
            margin: 0 10px !important;
            text-indent: -9999px; white-space: nowrap; outline: none;
            width: 56px; height: 100%;  filter:invert(1); 
            background-size: contain !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-image: url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/css-hero/logo.svg') !important;
            background-position:center !important;  background-color: transparent !important;
            }
        #wp-admin-bar-wpcss-css-hero-go:hover a {  filter:invert(0.8); } 
    </style>
                    <style type="text/css">
                    @font-face {font-family: "Chopin";font-display: auto;font-fallback: ;font-weight: 100;src: url(https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/ChopinScript.otf) format('OpenType');}                </style>
                    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <style>.bg{opacity: 0; transition: opacity 1s; -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;} .bg-loaded{opacity: 1;}</style><!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/ie-fallback.css"><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js"></script><script>var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],style = document.createElement('style');style.type = 'text/css';style.styleSheet.cssText = ':before,:after{content:none !important';head.appendChild(style);setTimeout(function(){head.removeChild(style);}, 0);</script><script src="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/libs/ie-flexibility.js"></script><![endif]-->   <noscript><style>.woocommerce-product-gallery{ opacity: 1 !important; }</style></noscript>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">#wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar > .ab-item{padding-right:26px !important;background: url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/plugins/what-the-file/assets/images/never5-logo.png')center right no-repeat !important;} #wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar.hover > .ab-item {background-color: #32373c !important; } #wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar #wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar-template-file .ab-item, #wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar #wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar-template-parts {text-align:right;} #wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar-template-parts.menupop > .ab-item:before{ right:auto !important; }#wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar-powered-by{text-align: right;}#wp-admin-bar-wtf-bar-powered-by a{color:#ffa100 !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
    
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="(no title)" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Premier XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/dummy-1.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="260" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
<meta name="twitter:text:title" content="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/dummy-1.jpg?w=640" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />

<!-- End Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Logo-Round-100x100.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Logo-Round-280x280.png" sizes="192x192" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Logo-Round-280x280.png" />
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Logo-Round-280x280.png" />
<style id="custom-css" type="text/css">:root {--primary-color: #446084;}.header-main{height: 150px}#logo img{max-height: 150px}#logo{width:290px;}.header-top{min-height: 25px}.transparent .header-main{height: 30px}.transparent #logo img{max-height: 30px}.has-transparent + .page-title:first-of-type,.has-transparent + #main > .page-title,.has-transparent + #main > div > .page-title,.has-transparent + #main .page-header-wrapper:first-of-type .page-title{padding-top: 60px;}.header.show-on-scroll,.stuck .header-main{height:70px!important}.stuck #logo img{max-height: 70px!important}.header-bg-color, .header-wrapper {background-color: rgba(129,36,229,0)}.header-bottom {background-color: #dd9933}.top-bar-nav > li > a{line-height: 31px }.header-wrapper:not(.stuck) .header-main .header-nav{margin-top: 2px }@media (max-width: 549px) {.header-main{height: 70px}#logo img{max-height: 70px}}.header-top{background-color:#000000!important;}body{font-family:"Lato", sans-serif}body{font-weight: 400}.nav > li > a {font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;}.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav > li > ul > li > a {font-family:"Lato", sans-serif;}.nav > li > a {font-weight: 700;}.mobile-sidebar-levels-2 .nav > li > ul > li > a {font-weight: 700;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.heading-font, .off-canvas-center .nav-sidebar.nav-vertical > li > a{font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,.heading-font,.banner h1,.banner h2{font-weight: 700;}.alt-font{font-family: "Dancing Script", sans-serif;}.alt-font{font-weight: 400!important;}@media screen and (min-width: 550px){.products .box-vertical .box-image{min-width: 247px!important;width: 247px!important;}}.footer-2{background-image: url('https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Footer.jpg');}.footer-1{background-color: rgba(0,117,191,0)}.page-title-small + main .product-container > .row{padding-top:0;}@media (max-width: 849px){#wpadminbar{display: none!important;}html{margin-top: 0!important}}@media (min-width: 850px){.mfp-content,.stuck,button.mfp-close{top: 32px!important;}.is-full-height{height: calc(100vh - 32px)!important;}}.xdebug-var-dump{z-index: 999999;}.shortcode-error{border: 2px dashed #000;padding: 20px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;background-color: #71cedf;}.custom-product-page .shortcode-error {padding: 15% 10%;text-align: center;}.edit-block-wrapper{position: relative;}.edit-block-button{font-size: 12px!important;background-color: #555!important;margin: 6px 2px 3px 0px!important;border-radius: 4px!important;}.edit-block-button-builder{background-color: #00a0d2!important;}.label-new.menu-item > a:after{content:"New";}.label-hot.menu-item > a:after{content:"Hot";}.label-sale.menu-item > a:after{content:"Sale";}.label-popular.menu-item > a:after{content:"Popular";}</style>    <style id="egf-frontend-styles" type="text/css">
        p {} h1 {} h2 {} h3 {} h4 {} h5 {} h6 {}    </style>
        <!-- Fonts Plugin CSS - https://fontsplugin.com/ -->
    <style>
            </style>
    <!-- Fonts Plugin CSS -->
    </head>

<body class="home page-template page-template-page-transparent-header-light page-template-page-transparent-header-light-php page page-id-55 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support theme-flatsome woocommerce-no-js lightbox nav-dropdown-has-arrow nav-dropdown-has-shadow nav-dropdown-has-border">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var request, b = document.body, c = 'className', cs = 'customize-support', rcs = new RegExp('(^|\\s+)(no-)?'+cs+'(\\s+|$)');

                request = true;
    
            b[c] = b[c].replace( rcs, ' ' );
            // The customizer requires postMessage and CORS (if the site is cross domain).
            b[c] += ( window.postMessage && request ? ' ' : ' no-' ) + cs;
        }());
    </script>
```

Comment: `#page-header-1359185174`, `.title-bg`, `.title-overlay`, `.featured-title` etc is not present in the HTML. Can you share more info?

Comment: My site is down for maintanance but here is the demo sitenot sure if it will help. https://flatsome3.uxthemes.com/demos/